# If else statement in a tabularx

Tags: tabularx, conditionals

In the MWE below, I'm trying to build a table with 6 columns if statement is true.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newif\iftest
\testtrue

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!]
    \caption{foobar}
    \label{tab: foo}

    \iftest
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X  >{\centering}m{1.8cm} >{\centering}m{1.11cm} >{\centering}m{1.1cm} >{\centering}m{1.7cm} >{\centering}m{1.7cm}}
    \else
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X  >{\centering}m{1.8cm} >{\centering}m{1.11cm} >{\centering}m{1.1cm} >{\centering}m{1.7cm}}
    \fi    
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX complains that there is an extra else.
what am I missing?

```
Extra \else.

<inserted text> ... >{\centering }m{1.7cm}} \else 
                                                  \begin {tabularx}{\textwid...
l.20         \end{tabularx}

I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.
```

Comment: you could simply delete the test as the extra column declaration does not harm if it is not used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tabularx` environment is actually set up to read the body into a macro; see this excerpt from [the documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/tabularx) (section **3 Differences between `tabularx` and `tabular*`**):

> The body of the `tabularx` environment is in fact the argument to a command ...

The reason for this is because the table is set multiple times in order to get the correct widths of `X`-columns and capturing the body allows for processing it more than once quite easily. Since the body is captured, you end up with dangling `\else` or `\fi`s, depending on whether `\testtrue` or `\testfalse`.

One way around this is to store the `tabularx` definition inside a macro and call it outside the `\if`...`\fi` construction:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newif\iftest

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{foobar}

  \iftest
    \def\begintabularx{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X X }}
  \else
    \def\begintabularx{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X }}
  \fi
  \begintabularx
    % Your table here
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `tabularx` environment looks for the terminating `\end{tabularx}` and absorbs everything in between before starting its work.

In your case this makes `\else` or `\fi` inside a table cell, which is bad, because a conditional cannot straddle table cells.

It's not clear what would be the reason for having a different number of columns, but just for testing purpose, let's pretend this makes sense.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newif\iftest
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\checktest}{%
  \iftest\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}
\makeatother
\testtrue

\begin{document}

\checktest{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    X
    >{\centering}m{1.8cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.11cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.1cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.7cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.7cm}
  }
}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    X
    >{\centering}m{1.8cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.11cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.1cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.7cm}
  }
}
A & B & C & D & E \tabularnewline
A & B & C & D & E \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}

\testfalse

\checktest{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    X
    >{\centering}m{1.8cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.11cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.1cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.7cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.7cm}
  }
}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
    X
    >{\centering}m{1.8cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.11cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.1cm}
    >{\centering}m{1.7cm}
  }
}
A & B & C & D & E \tabularnewline
A & B & C & D & E \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This way, the conditional is evaluated *before* `tabularx` starts working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `tabularx` environment which was `\begin`ed inside the `\if` also needs to be `\end`ed inside the `\if`. (Think of `\begin{...}...\end{...}` and `\if...\fi` statements as pairs of brackets: they need to match up in the right order "`([])`" rather than "`([)]`", if you see what I mean...).

To meet your additional requirement that there is, really, only one table (not two), in your case I note that the last two columns are the same width. So, one solution is to define `\myval` to have value 2 if `test` is true, and 1 if not. You can then use `*{\myval}{>{\centering}m{1.7cm}}` in the specification of the `tabularx` which produces 2 or 1 copies of the final column.

If you want columns of different widths at the end, you'd probably need another solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newif\iftest
\testtrue

\newcommand\myval{\iftest2\else1\fi}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t!]
    \caption{foobar}
    \label{tab: foo}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X  >{\centering}m{1.8cm} >{\centering}m{1.11cm} >{\centering}m{1.1cm} *{\myval}{>{\centering}m{1.7cm}}}  
        1&2&3&4&5&6      
        \end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that's not really ideal because you've to copy majority of the text twice :/

Comment: Can you give some context? What is going in this table? It might be that you want to define a new environment for this...

Comment: From the second row onwards, the data is a blob of text that spans across all rows, instead of data for each column. so having to repeat most of the text in the latex file is not convenient

Comment: Updated solution above which might work for you.